# How to add text to generated elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna my code look like these:
[wanted appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUFKl.jpg)

I don' want to use css variables - it's not goood idea. How it's possible to make all html element look different? Is it possible to do it in one div?

```js
function createGrid(x, y) {
    for (var cols = 0; cols < x; cols++) {
        for (var rows = 0; rows < y; rows++) {
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'></div>");
        };
    };
    $('.grid').width(800 / x);
    $('.grid').height(800 / x);
};
function getData(count) {
    var names = ["Michał", "Jan", "Katarzyna", "Andrzej", "Józef", "Bartek", "Mikołaj", "Tomasz", "Julian", "Brajan", "Dżesika"];
    var surnames = ["Noga", "Kowalski", "Nowak", "Pazura", "Duda", "Komorowski", "Tomczyk", "Józefowicz", "Lechicki", "Goldberg"];
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var randomNameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        var randomSurnameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * surnames.length);
        var name = names[randomNameIndex];
        var surname = surnames[randomSurnameIndex];
        result.push({
            name: name,
            surname: surname
        });
    }

    return result
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
}
.grid{
    outline:5px solid white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    background-color: #212121;  
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```
<body>
 <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will inevitably end up using css, I suggest you this:

1.- you could define classes(red, white, gray, blut, etc), then in your `createGrid` logic select classes randomly.

2.- Or maybe play with a random background color and injected to your element.

but at the end is css. Is the only way to change the style.

Comment: Everything you've written is correct but I have array with names and I want to display these names inside of generated tiles (as you can see on screenshot).